# DateDiff in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, date, plsql, date-difference

**How to find difference between 2 timestamps in seconds?**

Is there any system function or I should manually calculate some second like this

```
SELECT t1_id,
EXTRACT(Day FROM(mod_date_time – create_date_time) DAY TO SECOND) as Day,
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(mod_date_time – create_date_time) DAY TO SECOND) as Hour,
EXTRACT(Minute FROM(mod_date_time – create_date_time) DAY TO SECOND) as Minute,
EXTRACT(SECOND FROM(mod_date_time – create_date_time) DAY TO SECOND) as second
FROM t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, dates are just numbers. Each day is 1 integer. Finding the seconds difference can be done as follows:

```
SELECT (mod_date_time - create_date_time) * 24 * 60 * 60 as "seconds_diff"
FROM t1
```

Comment: I get result +000007260 00:00:00.000000000, How to convert into number type? hawk

Comment: @asfasas You can always convert the results using a proper mask. What values you used for `mod_date_time` and `create_date_time` ?